# Message queues message receive gives error invalid argument

Tags: c, message-queue, msgrcv

Very new to message queues and I am getting an error when I send a message from pikabo.c to master.c. I initially thought there was something wrong with my msgget() but master is able to send a message to pikabo.c and pikabo is able to read it.

I'm writing these lines because otherwise my question is not posting.

This is my code:
**master.c**

```
//global variables
int shmid;
int msgid;
long currentprocessPID;
key_t shmkey;

struct mesg_buffer {
    long mesg_type;
    int mesg_text[4];
} message;
void startprocess()
{

    int i;
        pid_t pID = fork();
        if (pID < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to fork:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //launch user process and send a message to it using PID as msg type
        else if (pID == 0)
        {
            static char *args[]={"./pikabo",NULL};
            int status;
            if(( status= (execv(args[0], args)))==-1)
            {
                perror("failed to execv");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else
                printf("\n message sent to user sucessfully");
        }
        //send a message to user
        currentprocessPID=pID;
        message.mesg_type = currentprocessPID;
        if( msgsnd(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0)==-1)
            perror("error in sending message to user process");
        else
        {
            printf("\nmessage sent to process %ld",currentprocessPID);
            //do some stuff
        }
        //wait for a message back from user
        if(msgrcv(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), currentprocessPID, 0)==-1)
            perror("error in recieving message from user process");
        else
        {
            printf("\n%d process is done with its work",message.mesg_text[0]);
            int arg1=message.mesg_text[1];//cpu time used by the user process seconds
            int arg2=message.mesg_text[2];//cpu time used by the user process nanoseconds
        }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{      shmkey = ftok("makefile",777);
        if (shmkey == -1) {
            perror("Ftok failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
        msgid = msgget(shmkey, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        startprocess();
    return 0;
}
```

**pikabo.c**

```
int shmid;
struct mesg_buffer {
    long mesg_type;
    int mesg_text[4];
} message;
void main()
{
        long pid=getpid();
        printf("\n\nhello from %d",getpid());

        key_t shmkey = ftok("makefile",777);
        if (shmkey == -1) {
            perror("Ftok failed");}
        int msgid = msgget(shmkey, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        while(1)
            {
                if(msgrcv(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), getpid(), 0))
                {
                    printf("\nDate received");

                        message.mesg_type = pid;
                        message.mesg_text[0]=pid;
                        message.mesg_text[1] = locals;
                        message.mesg_text[2]=localn;
                        message.mesg_text[3]=1;
                        if( msgsnd(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0)==-1)
                            perror("error in sending message back");
                        exit(0);
                }
            }//endwhile
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The only reason I removed the headers was because my code was getting too long and I wasn't able to post it. Also, This is the minimum I had to type to reproduce the problem.

Comment: These are the headers: # include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <dirent.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <getopt.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <signal.h>
# include <sys/mman.h>
# include <sys/time.h>
# include <stdint.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <sys/shm.h>
# include "shmemsem.h"
# include <sys/ipc.h>
# include <semaphore.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <sys/ipc.h>
# include <sys/msg.h>